# Rogue "flushing' water pipe

Tags: water, pipe

I live in the ground floor flat of a converted Victorian House and have recently come across a rogue pipe that shoots water out sporadically into an external drain kind of like a toilet flush swoosh sound, but the water is clean. I have no idea where this is from or what it could be - Can anyone shed some light?
It is a white plastic pipe that comes from under the house (there is a basement, but it is tanked). I initially thought that it was noise from an upstairs toilet of a flat above, but saw it pump out with my own eyes today ( and subsequently make the drain at the side of the house overflow!)
I hope someone can help - thanks

Comment: Size of the pipe? And is the water really clean, or just clean-ish? (maybe soapy?)

Comment: Can you add a picture? It sounds like it might be a sump pump, as that's the typical "pumps out the side of the house" scenario, though that water is typically somewhat dirty. How does it make a drain overflow?

Comment: Also what does a "tanked" basement mean?

Comment: Could it be discharge from a sump pump?

Comment: Sump pump or water softener discharge?

Answer (score 2):

If this pipe is just above ground level and is spewing clean water out onto the ground (or is otherwise unchecked), it is more than likely coming from a sump. This sump could be from a drain tile or the A/C drain. If you have access to the basement, this can easily be determined by tracing the pipe back from where it goes through the wall/structure, unless it is all behind sheetrock.

(NOTE: I didn't see Tester101 and Fiasco Labs comments prior to writing this. I'm basically agreeing with them.)

Comment: Hmm yeah I like these ideas too. It appears it could be any or all of the above.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, plumbing codes have begun to require "trap primers" or an extra deep trap for floor drains to keep their traps full of water.

I would propose that is what you have here. To keep the external drain's trap filled with water the trap primer is occasionally pumping water into the drain.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap_primer

> More common is a primer that is connected to the potable water supply and activates when pressure fluctuations are sensed, such as the flushing of a nearby water closet.